# Linking order stipulates which version of a class is used in another template class, how can I control which version is used?

Tags: c++, cuda, linker

I'm working on some cross-platform code, and certain top-level abstractions contain the same code for CPU and GPU, while the lower-level code they call can be built for either device by checing the `__CUDACC__` flag, which is supposedly defined top-level by the NVCC compiler for everything it touches.

Unfortunately, it looks like code from some headers that should be compiled with NVCC is, for whatever reason, compiled as plain CPU code, while I need it to be compiled as CUDA code.

This minimal example explains what I mean better. All files in a zip archive, including the CMake, can be downloaded from [here](http://www.filedropper.com/cudaheaderproblemexample).

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ClassA.hpp"

int main() {
    ClassA<DEVICE_CPU> a_cpu_instance;
    a_cpu_instance.PrintDevice();
    a_cpu_instance.PrintClassBDevice();
    ClassA<DEVICE_CUDA> a_cuda_instance;
    a_cuda_instance.PrintDevice();
    a_cuda_instance.PrintClassBDevice();
    return 0;
}
```

**Device.hpp** simply contains an enum.

```
#pragma once

enum Device{
    DEVICE_CUDA,
    DEVICE_CPU
};
```

**ClassA.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Device.hpp"

template <Device device>
class ClassA{
public:
    void PrintDevice();
    void PrintClassBDevice();
};
```

**ClassA.tpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "ClassA.hpp"
#include "ClassB.hpp"

template<Device device>
void ClassA<device>::PrintDevice() {
    {
#if defined(__CUDACC__)
        printf("CUDA\n");
#else
        printf("CPU\n");
#endif
    }
}

template<Device device>
void ClassA<device>::PrintClassBDevice() {
    ClassB b_instance;
    b_instance.PrintDevice();
}
```

**ClassB.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
class ClassB{
public:
    void PrintDevice(){
#if defined(__CUDACC__)
        printf("CUDA\n");
#else
        printf("CPU\n");
#endif
    }

};
```

The files **ClassA_CPU.cpp** and **ClassA_CUDA.cu** simply contain the explicit instantiations of ClassA for each platform, e.g. ClassA_CUDA.cu contains

```
#include "ClassA.tpp"
template class ClassA<DEVICE_CUDA>;
```

This program prints:

```
CPU 
CPU 
CUDA 
CPU
```

Everything is good except for the last line. <s>I need `__CUDACC__` to be defined for ClassB header in the CUDA compilation unit (as guided by the .cu file), but it is not.</s> (It is, but the wrong version is used, see edit & answer) Also, suppose that `__CUDACC__` guides the actual definition of `ClassB`, not just implementation of `PrintDevice()`, and I want it to be compiled in the same unit, thus I cannot instantiate two different versions of `ClassB` in separate units from the `ClassA` units.

How can I do this?

P.S. feel free to lower the required CMake version in the provided file, I think it should work with anything >=3.9.

**[EDIT]** 2 new pieces of information.

1. Apparently, the order in which I specify files to CMake, i.e. `ClassA_CUDA.cu ClassA_CPU.cpp` vs. `ClassA_CPU.cpp ClassA_CUDA.cu`  determines which version of ClassB is used in **main.cpp**. I don't think there is any magic involved, but rather order of arguments to the linker that correspond to the compiled object files from those two units. For reference, I'm using the standard GCC linker (`ld`).
2. I know both versions of ClassB get compiled, since when I place warnings of the sort `#warning COMPILING CUDA VERSION` in the two different preprocessor branches within ClassB, I get both outputs (the "CUDA" one twice, for some reason).

[Side note: this question appears to be **more about linking C/C++ code with different defines** than anything else. CUDA users might have run into this more often, but really, if you simply compile one C++ unit with some '-D' flag and another without, not using CUDA at all, you'll get the same effect.]

Comment: You can try `nvcc -x cu` to force compilation of c++ files as cuda files. Or put the body of Class B in a .cu file.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'll see about that in a sec, but here's the mystery: when I place ```#warning COMPILING CUDA VERSION``` under ```if defined(__CUDACC__)``` inside ClassB, it actually does print out the warning during compilation... twice... I'm baffled.

Comment: @JHBonarius the ```-x cu``` is already on by default, apparently, virtue of CMake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the linker has essentially two equivalent sets of symbols for things in the class `ClassB`, and hence it will use the first one by default, depending on the linker order.

The solution is simply (although not obviously, at least to me) to template `ClassB` on `Device` as well, i.e.

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdio>

template <Device>
class ClassB{
public:
    void PrintDevice(){
#if defined(__CUDACC__)
        printf("CUDA\n");
#else
        printf("CPU\n");
#endif
    }

};
```

Obviously, this will require it to be decorated with the template argument when used in ClassA like so:

```
template<Device device>
void ClassA<device>::PrintClassBDevice() {
    ClassB<device> b_instance;
    b_instance.PrintDevice();
}
```

This will result in the compiler producing two differing sets of symbols, which will be properly differentiated during linking

Comment: This is still going to  do unexpected in some cases. If you compile a `DEVICE_CPU` instance within a .cu file, you will get "CUDA" behaviour, which is probably not what you want. Once you actually have GPU code to compile, things probably won't work as you expect either.

Comment: Yes, the trick is to keep track and not compile DEVICE_CPU code within .cu, and you have full control over this via explicit instantiations. And the GPU code (lots of it too) is working as expected already, so I'm happy with this solution.